# Show asks that have a duedate in future (not today) and that are not completed and that have duedates of '0000-00-00'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that have  tasks that have a "duedate" (to be completed by) column and a comp_status column. it also has a user id column

0 = uncomplete
1= complete

I want to do a query that shows tasks that dont have duedate of today but a duedate in the future and that have a comp_status = 0, I also want to show  tasks that have a duedate of '0000-00-00'

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from taskdetail where userid='" . $rec['id'] . "' and comp_status='0'  and  duedate > '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' or duedate = '0000-00-00'  order by duedate,importantlevel ASC");
```

For some reason some tasks that have a completed status are still showing? 
Can you help?

Comment: Use parentheses around the or like so: $query = mysql_query("select * from taskdetail where userid='" . $rec['id'] . "' and comp_status='0'  and  (duedate > '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' or duedate = '0000-00-00')  order by duedate,importantlevel ASC");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the you have an OR in your statement: or duedate = '0000-00-00' ... because of this, any record that has this quality will show up.  You need to group it with your other condition regarding the duedate, like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from taskdetail where userid='" . $rec['id'] . "' and comp_status='0'  and  (duedate > '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' or duedate = '0000-00-00')  order by duedate,importantlevel ASC");
```

Note the parenthesis ()

Comment: ok I am having another issue, I want to show overdue tasks that have a comp_status of 0 and have a due date that is less than or equal to today and that are not = '0000-00-00'. Still seems to be showing a tasks that have a due date in the future?

$query_over = mysql_query("select * from taskdetail where userid='" . $rec['id'] . "' and comp_status='0' and ( duedate != '0000-00-00' or duedate <= '".date("Y-m-d")."'  )  ")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Because you're using an OR in the duedate-checking clause, any date will fulfil those criteria: dates in the future are not "0000-00-00", after all. That OR should be an AND in this case. (It may be worth spending some more time studying boolean logic. :) )